# Is there a way to pull stock rom from android using adb and a non-rooted android device?

Tags: adb, stock-android, rom, device-firmware

I know that in a lot of cases adb can be powerful, but adb requires root access under certain circumstances, so my question is, if i wanted to pull my stock rom or firmware from my device, can i do it using adb and a non-rooted android device?

The reason for doing so is i know for a fact, hours of researching, that a few of my android devices do not have root availability due to locked bootloader and recovery, ext.

I want to make root available for my device any way i can, even if i have to build my own rom and flash it so it can flash other files (Samsung devices run through odin, and not fastboot)

NOTE: I am NOT looking to backup my device, i simply want the stock files so i can create custom flashable files for odin. Also, i do intend on rooting my device later, so temporary root, could help achieve what i want.

Comment: I happily stand corrected, but AFAIK that's not possibĺe. Even if it were, you couldn't flash back your own ROM without unlocking the bootloader, so you'd be stuck in that last step anyway. But what I'm not sure about is whether Odin itself can do that (I have no Samsung devices, no Windows and thus no Odin to check); I know that for MTK devices, MTK Flashtool is capable of that.

Comment: I doubt you can do it without root. I also do not know if you can do this from the system. I am sure you need to do it from a custom recovery such as TWRP since the stock recovery has minimal adb support. You need to locate the  and dump the desired partition the use the command `and pull` the block file from said partition. **example only** the command should look something like:  `pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 mmcblk0.img`

Comment: @BoLawson I know for a fact i have pulled a stock img from a non-rooted device using adb in the past, i cannot remember how. I actually plan to build my own twrp image for use on my device and yes Odin is an alternative to fast boot, just Samsung's take on it, and it has nothing but flashing a few small commands like flash reset. I plan on taking the stock images and making them Odin compatible (iv'e done this before, just been so long i don't remember how to pull my stock files)
Using dirty cow or another exploit to gain temporary root could be useful for this im thinking.